# Is -10 between 1.5 × 10^-45 and 3.4 × 10^38?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, floating-point, c#-3.0

### Is -10 between 1.5e-45 and 3.4e+38?

If yes, explain to me why. I am no more that good in Maths. So, sorry for the weakness of these questions level.

According to [C# documentation *(of computer programming for that language)* on Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables), their variables float type is between 1.5 × 1e-45 and 3.4 × 1e+38?

But, **1e-3** equals **0.001** and **1e-6** equals **0.000001**. That means the more we decrease a negative exponent, the less will be the resulting value but that one will still greater than zero.

Here comes the problem, I tried to use a float variable giving to it **-10** as value expecting to get an error but to my surprise, **-10** was accepted. 
I am confused.

Comment: The documentation is lacking details about this, but you can have both negative and positive numbers.

Comment: There is also a comment at the bottom of that page to this effect.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The description of `decimal` seems to be even more absurd: `range is at least -7.9 × 10^-28 to 7.9 × 10^28`: `-7.9 × 10^-28` is a negative number that is very very very small and near 0.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation doesn't say so explicitly, but the two floating-point types are signed. So -10 can be represented by a floating-point type just as 10 can.

Comment: The correct range for *float* is described by IEEE-754 [single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Single_precision). The range for *double* is [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double_precision). Note the `±`used there. There are also representations of +0 and -0.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things to note.

The first is that `float` (and for that matter, `double`) is signed, so the values can be either positive or negative (or zero).

The other is that the range is a matter of precision. If you try to set a `float` to a value of less absolute value than than it can handle, like `1E-50` it will be set to zero rather than error; which is what you get when you round 1×10<sup>-50</sup> to the precision it can cope with, while if you try to give it a value larger than the absolute value it can handle, like `1E50` then it will be set to ∞ (or -∞ for `-1E50`) because again that's as precisely as it can represent something that large.

Comment: On a similar note, if you try `((float)1234567890) == ((float)1234568000)` you will get a result of `true` because it rounds them to the same value, while if you try `((double)1234567890) == ((double)1234568000)` you will get a result of `false` because `double` can handle more precision.

Answer (score 0):

That C# documentation is poorly written and has some errors or omissions:

- The range it describes is only for the **magnitude** of positive finite numbers. The floating-point formats also include zero, negative numbers, and infinities. Thus, the true range is from −∞ to +∞.
- It uses approximate decimal values to describe the range. The true values for `float` are:

  - The smallest representable positive number is exactly 2<sup>−149</sup>, which is 1.40129846432481707092372958328991613128026194187651577175706828388979108268586060148663818836212158203125e-45.
  - The largest representable finite number is exactly 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>, which is 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.